# xfce » xfce4-panel » tasklist / Window Buttons: set custom font

Tags: xfce, xubuntu

I'd like to change the font size of the entries for each application listed by the "tasklist" plugin. 
Is there any way to do that?

I thought this site would help:
https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/tasklist .
But it does not mention font sizing and also not the place of the config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**until 18.04**

- Open / Create ~/.gtkrc-2.0

  - Here you can set all kinds of specific styles
- Insert the following code:

  ```
  style "window-buttons"
  {
      font_name = "Arial 17"
      XfceTasklist::max-button-size = 32
  }
  ```
- restart your panel: `xfce4-panel -r`

**explanation**

- style `Window-Buttons` is used by the widget(?) "Window-Buttons", which is the name for the tasklist. I found this information [here](https://github.com/shimmerproject/Greybird/blob/master/gtk-2.0/apps/xfce-panel.rc)
- `XfceTasklist::max-button-size = 32` changes the button size (if you miss that, text will be cropped on the top and bottom. Information [here](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=3218)
- If you want to change all sizes instead, see [this link](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=3218)
- General rc-file information [is here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Resource-Files.html)

**from 18.10**

You need to use gtk3. I couldn't get it to work here, but apparently you use the file ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
[Here](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/theming) is an information page (that doesen't work for me right now)